# How to make videos load quicker

Tags: help, mobile

Whenever I watch non-YouTube type videos on Tor with my phone, it takes forever to load. The bar fills much slower than it plays, so unless I have it paused at 0:00 for tens of minutes at a time, I generally won't see the full thing. Also, scrolling back more than, say, a minute and it will all unload.
However, when I was on my tablet they all loaded much better, more than one second's loading every second, making for a continuous watch. The issue is though that I powered off my tablet earlier and now it loads like my phone. I thought it was to do with the difference in RAM hardware until I powered my tablet off.

Basically, how can I make videos run vaguely faster as I have seen them do before?

Comment: I don't know about smartphones, but in a regular PC you can compile Tor to have only 2 hops in their circuits: https://www.grepular.com/Tor_Circuits_with_Two_Hops_on_Ubuntu - It turns Tor less anonymous, but I think is enough if you just want to watch videos.